# How do you find the critical points and max/mins using two graph?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

The two graphs are shown below.

[image: calculus 1]

Comment: Please, for the sake of those trying to read the question, keep your picture right-side-up

Comment: By looking at it?

Comment: Yes, by looking at it.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the critical points of $h$ are the values of $x$ for which $h'(x) = 0$.

By the chain-rule, we have
$$
h'(x) = f'(g(x))\cdot g'(x)
$$
So that $x$ will be a critical point of $h$ when either $g(x)$ is a critical point of $f$ or $x$ is a critical point of $g$.

For example, $f'(2) = 0$.  So, $x$ will be a critical point of $h$ if $g(x) = 2$.  So, $h$ has a critical point at $x = 4.5$.  What other critical points does $h$ have?

Note that $h$ will be increasing whenever $h'(x)$ is positive, and decreasing whenever $h'(x)$ is negative.